# SQL syntax Error on Java Jersey GET CRUD operation

Tags: sql, jersey

I'm trying to retrieve the information of the faculty with the students attending it and the subjects corresponding to the student.

**Here is the SQL error:**

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM faculty f
         inner join student_faculty sf on sf.student_id=s.user_id'
```

Here is the picture in line **116** the **s.user_id** is not on yellow color indicating something not right:
[image]

**Here is it how I want it to look like:**

```
{
  "fid": "1",
  "name": "Mathematcis",
  "enrolled_students": [
    {
      "id": "student1",
      "username": "user",
      "full_name": "userstudent",
      "subjects": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Programim 1"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Programim 2"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Calculus"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Discrete mathematics"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**Here is how postman shows it:**
[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
 public Faculty  getFacultyStudent(int id) throws Exception {
        Connection connection = null;

        Faculty faculty = new Faculty();
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSubjectList(new ArrayList<>());
        faculty.setStudentList(new ArrayList<>());

        try {
            connection = new MysqlDbConnectionService().getConnection();


            String select = "SELECT f.fid,\n" +
                    "      f.fname,\n" +
                    "      f.university_id,\n" +
                    "       s.user_id,\n" +
                    "       s.username,\n" +
                    "       s.password,\n" +
                    "       s.fullname,\n" +
                    "       s.email,\n" +
                    "       subj.id,\n" +
                    "       subj.name,\n" +
                    "FROM faculty f\n" +
                    "         inner join student_faculty sf on sf.student_id=s.user_id\n" +
                    "         INNER JOIN student s ON sf.student_id=s.user_id\n" +
                    "         INNER JOIN faculty_subject fs on f.fid = fs.faculty_id\n" +
                    "         inner join subject subj on fs.subject_id = subj.id\n" +
                    "WHERE fid = ?;";

            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(select);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


            while (rs.next()) {
                if(faculty.getFid()==0) {
                   faculty.setFid(rs.getInt("fid"));
                   faculty.setFname(rs.getString("fname"));
                }
                student.setId(rs.getString("user_id"));
                student.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                student.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                student.setFullName(rs.getString("fullname"));
                student.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));

                Subject subject=new Subject();
                subject.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                subject.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                student.getSubjectList().add(subject);

                faculty.getStudentList().add(student);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e + "Retrieve not successful");

        }

        return faculty;


    }
```

**Faculty Class:**

```
package com.common.db.domain;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Faculty {


    @SerializedName("id")
    private int fid;

    @SerializedName("university_id")
    private int university_id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String fname;

    @SerializedName("Enrolled Students:")
    private List<String> studentList;


    public Faculty() {
        this.fid = fid;
        this.university_id=university_id;
    }

    public  void setFid(int fid)
    {

        this.fid = fid;
    }

    public int getFid()
    {

        return fid;
    }

    public  void setUniversityid(int university_id)
    {

        this.university_id=university_id;
    }

    public int getUniversityid()
    {

        return university_id;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname)
    {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getFname()
    {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setStudentList(List<String> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    public List<Object> getStudentList()
    {
        return Collections.singletonList(studentList);
    }

}
```

**Student Class:**

```
package com.common.db.domain;


import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class Student {


    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;

    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    @SerializedName("fullname")
    private String fullName;

    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("subjects")
    private List<Subject> subjectList;


    public Student() {

    }


    public Student(String id, String username, String password, String fullName, String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.email = email;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Subject> getSubjectList() {
        return subjectList;
    }

    public void setSubjectList(List<Subject> subjectList) {
        this.subjectList = subjectList;
    }
}
```

**Subject Class:**

```
package com.common.db.domain;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Subject {




    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;


    public Subject() {
        this.id = id;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public  void setId(int id)
    {
      this.id=id;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }



}
```

**Here is my ER Diagram:**

[image: Er Diagram]

Comment: why do you have all those breaklines in your query? Either way, your question is not exactly java related

Answer (score 0):

I was reading through the code and the error and it appears to be just your sentence.

`"subj.name , \n" +  "FROM faculty f\n" +`

That comma after the column name and before the FROM clause is causing that error.
Try to remove it and test it again

Comment: The same Error in line 116 appears java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 's.user_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: I was taking a look to your query and the reason why is throwing that error is because the inner join clauses. I almost sure that the design of the database as well is causing some difficulties (1 student can have multiple faculties at one university? and 1 subject can have multiple faculties) but i don't know the use case for this. I would recommend to change the relation between faculty to student making student table having the FK of the faculty id so 1 student can have 1 faculty but 1 faculty can have multiple students  (same suggestion on subjects) after that the query is gonna be simple

Comment: How would you structure the query based on my current database schema without making changes to the database, maybe if I write the query differently it might work.

Comment: I would say something like: SELECT f.fid, f.fname, f.university_id,
       s.user_id, s.username, s.password, s.fullname, s.email,
FROM student_faculty sf
INNER JOIN faculty f ON f.fid = sf.faculty_id
INNER JOIN student s ON s.user_id = sf.student_id 
WHERE sf.faculty_id = ? UNION
SELECT subj.id, subj.name
FROM faculty_subject fs
INNER JOIN subject subj ON subj.id = fs.subject_id
WHERE fs.faculty_id = ? Im not 100% sure that this will work coz I didnt test it but should work

Comment: I got this error now: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2

Comment: On your prepared statement assignation of parameters add `ps.setInt(2,id);` before `ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();`

Comment: Error is now: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: Dont delete the `ps.setInt(1,id);` leave it there just add the `ps.setInt(2,id);` after it. Like this `ps.setInt(1,id); ps.setInt(2,id); ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();`

Comment: New Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM student_faculty sf INNER JOIN faculty f ON f.fid = sf.faculty_id INNER JOIN'

Comment: My bad I left a comma before the first FROM, just remove it

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columnsRetrieve not successful

Comment: Well in this case then the query that i did is wrong. I would either suggest to execute 2 different queries (the first one before the `union` and the second one after the `union`) and retrieve the data or to simply use subquery to retrieve the data from the subject table. Again the way the tables are design is making that the query is harder than is supposed to be but those 2 are the options that came in my mind if you don't want to change your schema